# Using Karate Framework run SQL query against SQL Server DB running in docker

Tags: sql-server, karate

Our SQL Server DB in running in docker container. I am using karate framework for testing. Below is my karate script. DB container is up and running but still I get error.

> org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.*

My Script
Feature: Connect to DB

Background:

- def config = { username: 'sa', password: '*******', url: 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName=abc', driverClassName: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' }

  - def DbUtils = Java.type('demo_upload.users.DbUtils')
  - def db = new DbUtils(config)

  Scenario: Read Rows in question Table
- def question = db.readRows("'select * from question'")

I have tried restarting db still seeing same error.
Note: I run my karate tests in docker as well.

Comment: I suggest running `Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 1433` in a powershell prompt to test network connectivity to your SQL Server. You might not have the internal port mapped to an exrternal port in docker. What does your dockerfile look like?

Comment: thank you for your response. I was able to connect. I just needed to add network name of my db in my docker run command. My Karate tests are also running in docker.

Comment: It would be handy of you could document your solution (including code) as an answer and accept it